# Could a quantum computer perform vectorized forward propagation in deep networks?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, quantum-computing, forward-pass

### Forward propagation in Deep Neural Networks

In the "Forward Propagation in a Deep Network" video on Coursera, Andrew NG mentions that there's no way to avoid a for loop to loop through the different layers of the network during forward propagation.

See image showing a deep network with 4 layers, and the requirement of a forloop to compute activations for each layer during forward propagation: https://nimb.ws/CkRVLT

This makes intuitive sense since each layer's activation depends on the previous layer's output.

### Warning: start of speculation

My rudimentary understanding of quantum computing is that it somehow "magically" can bypass computing intermediate states -> this is why supposedly quantum computers can break cryptography... or something like that.

I'm wondering if a quantum computer could perform vectorized forward propagation on an L layer deep neural network.

Comment: just commenting to point out the existence of [quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/), in case you were not aware of the site